# I get "Cannot access org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" error, When I upgraded activemq-all version from 5.16.3 to 5.17.2

Tags: maven, activemq-classic

I upgraded activemq-all version from 5.16.3 to 5.17.2. When I run the application, I get this error:

```
java: cannot access org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
  bad class file: /E:/<username>/.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.17.2/activemq-all-5.17.2.jar!/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory.class
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

And when I run maven build also:

```
cannot access org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
```

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Java **11** to use ActiveMQ "Classic" 5.17.x. Note that the download page on the [ActiveMQ website](https://activemq.apache.org/components/classic/download/) says this about 5.17.2:

```
Java compatibility: 11+
```

You apparently are using Java 8 still which is why you're getting this error:

```
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
```

If you can't upgrade your version of Java you should continue using 5.16.x.